# Ember Simple Auth Change Default Store

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm new to ember and ember-simple-auth. My app uses Pods mode. Currently I'm building a login page and want to use SessionStorageStore to store user information, so that the info stored in session storage will be cleaned after closing the browser. Ember-simple-auth uses local storage by default. How can I change the default store? The method mentioned in the API doc seems not work for me. The info is still stored in the local storage. Any ideas how to change the default store?[My Project Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LazDL.png)

Comment: Please, share an example of what you tried so far and where are you stuck.

Comment: remove the `./` in the beginning of your import

Comment: @Lux Thanks! Yep,  I made some mistakes here. And by the way, it seems I need to restart ember server again in order to make SessionStorageStore work.